# Run-time error 451 When Attempting to Retrieve Class Dictionary

Tags: excel, vba, class

I'm getting a **run-time error 451** when attempting to retrieve a dictionary as a property of my class.  It says

> Property let procedure note defined and property get procedure did not return an object.

Here is the main subroutine code and then the class code, in the main subroutine the first message box works wheras the second message box (which I'm intending on returning the same data as the first) throws the error:

The main module:

```
Sub Main()

'Declaring [BD]
Dim oHeaderDictionary As New Scripting.Dictionary

'Initializing [BD]
Set oThisSlider = New Slider
Set oHeaderDictionary = New Scripting.Dictionary

Worksheets("Options").Activate

iLastRow = bpLastRow("B")

For iRowIncrementer = 3 To iLastRow
    sColumnHeaders = Cells(iRowIncrementer, 2).Value
    sColumnStyles = Cells(iRowIncrementer, 3).Value
    oHeaderDictionary.Add sColumnHeaders, sColumnStyles
Next iRowIncrementer

MsgBox oHeaderDictionary.Items(1)

oThisSlider.Headers = oHeaderDictionary

MsgBox oThisSlider.Headers.Items(1)

End Sub
```

And the class module:

```
'Declaring [BD]
Private m_oHeaders As Scripting.Dictionary

'Initializing [BD]
'==========================================================================================
' [BD] Properties
'==========================================================================================
Property Get Headers() As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set Headers = m_oHeaders
End Property
Property Let Headers(oHeaders As Scripting.Dictionary)
    Set m_oHeaders = oHeaders
End Property
```

Any ideas on why this error is occurring and what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option Explicit is your friend. You've got to declare oThisSlider as a Slider object for it to work.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()

    'Declaring [BD]
    Dim oHeaderDictionary As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim oThisSlider As Slider
    Dim iLastRow As Long
    Dim iRowIncrementer As Long
    Dim sColumnHeaders As String
    Dim sColumnStyles As String

    'Initializing [BD]
    Set oThisSlider = New Slider
    Set oHeaderDictionary = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Worksheets("Options").Activate

    iLastRow = bpLastRow("B")

    For iRowIncrementer = 3 To iLastRow
        sColumnHeaders = Cells(iRowIncrementer, 2).Value
        sColumnStyles = Cells(iRowIncrementer, 3).Value
        oHeaderDictionary.Add sColumnHeaders, sColumnStyles
    Next iRowIncrementer

    MsgBox oHeaderDictionary.Items(1)

    oThisSlider.Headers = oHeaderDictionary

    MsgBox oThisSlider.Headers.Items(1)

End Sub
```

Comment: Great, thank you!  Just as I was thinking that I should leave option explicit off when building so I can build more on the fly I'm given a good reason to not do that!